# QT creator generate EXE file for windows or .dmg for mac osx

Tags: c++, qt-creator, exe, dmg

I have a question how to generate executables for Windows or .dmg for Mac OSX in Qt Creator. Please use easy way. I´m a beginner with QT creator.

How to build mac osx app without Mac and how to build linux app without linux.
I have a Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well in case of windows when you build and run a project, an executable in already generated in you project build directly.

and if you want to deploy it you have to use the command

```
windeployqt "path to qt project"
```

Note: the command is present in C:\Qt\5.3\mingw482_32\bin

more info available [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/40061/the-windeployqt-tool-that-comes-with-qt-5-2/7)